# Bootstrap 3: Remove overflow without adding padding

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a very nested layout and I sadly designed it without the container-fluid. Now I have the bad overflow. It should be a mobile app via cordova so overflow-x is not an option for me. If I add the container-fluid the overflow goes away but now every element has padding to the x-borders. 
There are some elements that are nested like col-4 col-6 col-2 and should be 100% but now there is padding to the right and left.

Do you have a tip how I can fix these problems without starting from 0?
Example:

```
<div class="container-fluid fl">
<div class="row content-begin">
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <br>
                        <h1>Title</h1>
                        <br>

                        <p>Lorem dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo Lorem dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam. </p>
                            <p><a>remove container-fluid</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div><!-- content -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r4w2zLre/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the provided JSFiddle example, you suggest to remove the `container-fluid`. 
By doing so your rows are not wrapped in a container anymore. But this is required by Bootstrap. You must either wrap in a `container` or in a `container-fluid`.

[See Bootstrap's grid documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid):

> Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.